# Laptop charger 120w Adapter as replacement for 19V 3,42A 65w

Tags: laptop, adapter, replacement

Is it safe 120W Laptop Charger, which has many output features as below? [Chinese brand adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001218252042.html) has many electrical specifications which are over my understanding.
My original Asus adapter has 19V 3.42A 65w output.
Or could long usage be harmful to the battery?

[image: output features]

Comment: What's your laptop and the original charger?

Answer (score 1):

Watts = volts x amps. Given that the voltage is what matters most and is fixed for the laptop, this is why your original 3.42 amp adapter is 65 watts.

The problem I see with the list on the 100W adapter is that it does not list 19V. The voltage *must* be the same.

If the voltage matches exactly what the laptop requires (and the plug matches the laptop connector), then derive the amps from the listed wattage (or the wattage from the listed amperage). The amps provided by the adapter should be at least what the OEM adapter lists. The adapter will not "force the extra watts" into the laptop.

Comment: Volts x Amps != Watts.  Volts x Amps = VA.  See http://www.generatorguide.net/watt-acpower.html

Comment: 1W = 1V x 1A by definition. Also, 1 VA = 1 W. In addition, 19 x 3.42 = ~65. I think we can agree that for the purposes of shopping, this is sufficiently true.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-maskitorcasket V*A= VA=W because the output is DC not AC.

Comment: @yorik this is only sufficiently true for DC (which is the case her). For AC you can easily land up with an underspecced ups - The difference between a watt and a VA can be 30%

Answer (score 0):

If your device can be powered over a USB port (usually USB-C) it will work for you.  Unfortunately the majority of devices arnt - if you have a typical power supply it won't work.

The reason is that device will be using USB PD - which means it will negotiate the voltage with the receiving device if the receiving device  handles USB pd - which practically speaking means a USB-C powered laptop.

When sizing a power supply -

You need to ensure the current is at least as much as your laptop needs. It won't hurt for the current rating to be higher - and arguably will help in terms of reliability.

Generally power rating needs to be within 5% - so 20 volts - while not recommended - would just about be OK if your current voltage output is 19 volts. (Does not apply here because if its usb-pd it will work, if not its not compatible)

An adaptor with to high a voltage might, but us unlikely to affect the battery - the laptop should have circuitry in it to control/regulate power and battery charge.

Comment: and just in case (for the OP): "Current" is the Amps value

Comment: My original Asus adapter is not Usb-C type. My plan is to buy C Female Jack Connector. https://i.imgur.com/iQvZ1HT.png

Comment: @Karakaplan This wont work. The result will only output 5 volts as there will be nothing to negotiate 19/20 volts for PD.